# Fiat500 not going into 2nd gear

Tags: gears, fiat

Hi I was driving my car and all of a sudden it won’t go into 2nd gear. All of my other gears work perfectly fine but when I put it into second it just jumps straight back into neutral and revs my engine. Does anyone know what this could be?

Comment: My car is a 2011 fiat 500

Comment: Perhaps the linkage has slipped. Needs checking...